# How do I set a variable inside a recipe using a case statement?

Tags: shell, makefile, switch-statement, gnu-make

I have the following code snippet and can't work out why it doesn't work:

```
test-%:
    # this works
    case $* in a) echo A;; b) echo B;; esac
    # this doesn't
    $(eval MY_VAR := \
        $(shell case $* in a) echo A;; b) echo B;; esac ))
    echo $(MY_VAR)
```

Output:

```
$ make test-a
bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
case a in a) echo A;; b) echo B;; esac
A
echo B;; esac ))
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
bash: -c: line 0: `echo B;; esac ))'
makefile:277: recipe for target 'test-a' failed
make: *** [test-a] Error 1
```

I suspect that I need to escape some characters but I don't know which. I tried \) which fixed the syntax highlighting in vim but that still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the shell shortcut for `case` which allows you to omit the opening parenthesis because `$(eval …)` needs matching parentheses.  Instead you need to write this:

```
    $(eval MY_VAR := \
        $(shell case $* in (a) echo A;; (b) echo B;; esac ))
```

(Also `$(eval …)`, even when nested in recipes like this, will still be parsed as a top-level makefile fragment, but perhaps this is what you want.

Comment: Or you could use curly-braces for the eval: `${eval MY_VAR := ...}`  But I always use the matching parens version of `case` anyway, even in shell scripts.

Comment: Thank you @Florian. That works. I'm not sure I understand your top-level makefile fragment comment but the code now works as I want it to.

Comment: The `$(eval)` will be parsed just as _make_ is expanding the recipe. It will not be parsed if the recipe is never invoked. Also, the _eval_ will be expanded _before_ the first line is passed to the shell, so it's a bit misleading to bury it in the middle of the recipe.